# Need help identifying odd rough-in drains in basement (that don't match anything I've seen online)

Tags: plumbing, rough-in

The attached photo shows five roughed in drains in my basement. These are in a 55" wide hallway that runs past the under-stairs area and the HVAC area.
As viewed front to back:

- a single 2" drain is placed 24" from the hallway opening, and 24" out from the left wall
- then 18" further afield are two side-by-side 2" that are 24" and 29" from the left wall respectively
- then 24" further back and at the far right of the photo in the shadow (54" from the left wall, and 2" from the right wall) is another 2"
- and then another 24" further back and 18" from the left wall is a 4" (certainly the toilet)

The magic question is what are all the 2" drains for?
Their spacing doesn't make sense when put in context of their proximity to the walls, and the general layout of the space. Thanks for any insight[image]

Comment: Is there any provision for a vent in the wall or ceiling? Shower, toilet, lav sink & laundry sink, washer, vent maybe? Sink & washer & vent come up in walls, toilet and shower from floor. If they are all connected you can draw up your own bath/laundry plans around it.

Comment: With all the bits of life in the way, it might help if you shared a drawing with the dimensions written on it.

Comment: Well, *some* of them are surely **vents** - so, one for tub/shower, one for lavatory (drains) one is probably primarily venting the toilet, perhaps there were plans for a bidet or a utility sink not in the bathroom, or a second vent. These things are always annoying to figure out when the plans have gone missing - you might see if plans are on file with your permitting authority.

Answer (score 1):

You can map out the plumbing yourself. A decent waterproof borescope camera with a long USB cord or even wireless can be purchased in the familiar online marketplaces at a relatively affordable price (say, US$20-40). Push one of those down through one of these pipes, perhaps with the help of an electrical fish tape or flexible fish rods, and make notes of the type and location of fittings you see from the inside. Draw them with chalk on the concrete floor. Run the camera through more of the pipe stubs as needed until the connections are all identified.

Because the caps may be cemented in place I'd begin working at the tallest pipes first and remove as little as possible of the pipe itself. You could possibly remove the caps without damaging the pipe at all (eg by sanding them off), or you could drill a hole through the top of a cap, do the work with the camera, and solvent-weld a scrap of ABS plastic to repair the hole. There also are knock-out test caps available; these glue to the end face of the pipe rather than its sides. You could cut off the dome part of a cap and re-seal the pipe by cementing one of these onto/into the cut face. (photo: Home Depot/Oatey)

[image: ABS test cap]

When you have the pipe layout and size mapped out it'll be much easier to figure out how these could be used -- which may or may not be the same as "what did the builder *intend* them for?" :-)

Comment: Wouldn't this require a locator with depth finder, and how would you determine diameter? Some guesswork still involved?

Comment: @P2000 For the ten or so feet of pipe in question here a utility locator, sonde, etc are an unnecessary luxury. If one works carefully it's possible to see in the camera view when a bend in the pipe is approaching, which direction it turns, and by how much (tee, wye, 90 degree elbow should be easy to identify for example). If the camera cord is marked for length before insertion, or pulled back and laid across the floor after finding a fitting, the path distance and the approximate position can be estimated.